# Windows 8 - Using External HDD as Storage Drive?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I wanted to know some opinions on a setup like this:

Have 2 External Hard Drives (1TB each) - I'll call them HDD1 and HDD2.

I would set most of my folders where I keep data (My Documents, My Pictures, My Videos, etc) to be on HDD1. Then, using Windows Synctoy and Task Scheduler, every night while I am not using the computer, I would back up one HDD to another one. This eliminates the worry about the external HDD failing as I could quickly set everything over to the other HDD.

So, I want to know if there any other disadvantages to a setup like this? I like it as I could move my files as needed, if I need a new computer it is easy to setup, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

StackExchange does not like opninion based questions - I don't see the problem in having a discussion and point out issues with any plan.  Every environment is unique and asking for a way to do something (or the flaws in a particular plan) from professionals should not be frowned upon in my opinion.

So, that said, your plan makes some sense except that external drives (at least most of them) are VERY slow (EVEN USB 3 drives but especially USB 2 drives) compared to the internal interface of the computer.  So while you could do that - and indeed, there may be practical instances where you want to (I do something very similar - without the sync - on my tablet with only a 32 GB drive (25% of which is occupied by recovery information)).

If you're willing to spend the money on SSDs and have USB 3 connections, I've seen some SSD drives that rival internal throughput when connected via USB3.  You could also potentially use eSATA connected drives to bypass the speed issue.

There are a couple other things you should consider:

- Such a plan does not protect you against fire, theft, or other
  disaster that affects BOTH drives because both drives are normally
  kept within feet if not inches of each other.
- External drives are more prone to being accidentally disconnected
  (the cat walks on the   cables, you bump into the machine, etc).

Because this is not one of those scenarios where your C: drive is extremely limited and you have no room for a second internal drive (like a tablet), I'd suggest you infest in an online backup system as that should help protect you against the bigger disasters.  Many online backup services exist and most would cost you annually about the price of an external hard drive.